# Binary to Decimal Conversion in Haskell using Horners Algorithm

Tags: function, haskell, binary, data-conversion

I am trying to implement a function here which takes a list of Bool representing binary numbers such as `[True, False, False]` and convert that into corresponding decimal number according to Horners method.

Function type would be `[Bool] -> Int`.

Algorithms which i am following is:

Horners Algorithm Visual Explanation:

[image]

So far i have implemented the logic in which it says first it will check whether the list is empty or either one element in the list `[True]`, will give 1 and `[False]` will give 0.

Then in this case `binToDecList (x:xs)  =  binToDecList' x 0` what i did to treat first element whether this is True or False.

```
binToDecList :: [Bool] -> Int
binToDecList []      = error "Empty List"
binToDecList [True]  = 1
binToDecList [False] = 0
binToDecList (x:xs)  =  binToDecList' x 0 
binToDecList' x d | x == True = mul (add d 1)
                  | otherwise = mul (add d 0)

add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add x y = x + y

mul :: Int -> Int
mul x = x * 2
```

I want to use the result of `binToDecList'` in the next iteration calling itself recursively on the next element of the list. How can i store the result and then apply it to next element of the list recursively. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using a `fold`.

Comment: This is a little simpler if you just convert the `[Bool]` value to a `[Int]` value list right away with `map fromEnum`: `binToDecList = go . map fromEnum where go = ...`.

Comment: Look up the documentation for `foldl` in the [Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html) and then try to fill the missing definition of the `go` helper function: `binToDecList = foldl go 0 where go acc x =  ...`

Comment: Thanks guys, i was able to perform this with fold function but still i want to know why it couldnt carried out with explicit recursion? Secondly there is one problem left that is, it is performing one extra iteration to multiply the result. How can i control that here. I tried this way if the next element is [ ] then it will just return the result accumulated so far. But it seems not be running as expected may be the composition of the calling functions isn't right?

Comment: Please guide: foldl(\result x -> if x == True then (mul(add result 1) xs) else (mul(add result 1) xs)) 0 xs  and mul :: Int -> [Bool]->Int
mul x b = if tail(b) /= [] then x * 2 else x   . I know this logic might not be so good here but i would like to carry out this way for now, unless i am going in wrong direction. Any help?

Comment: According to your concept, binToDecList' is a helper function. So, you should pass whole list to that function instead of passing only single element. 
Then try to write recursive code for that helper function.
For example: binToDecList fullList      = binToDecList'  fullList 0. Now induction is possible over the list using extra variable which will store your actual answer.

Comment: @RajibTheKing Thanks it worked with recursion. I am also trying to do with foldl function. Need help with above posted logic with foldl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type<sup>*****</sup> of `foldl` tells us how it must work.

```hs
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Clearly `[a]`, the third argument that is a list of something, must be the list of `Bool` to be handed to Horner’s algorithm. That means the type variable `a` must be `Bool`.

The type variable `b` represents a possibly distinct type. We are trying to convert `[Bool]` to `Int`, so `Int` is a decent guess for `b`.

`foldl` works by chewing through a list from the left (*i.e.*, starting with its head) and somehow combining the result so far with the next element from the list. The second argument is typically named `z` for “zero” or the seed value for the folding process. When `foldl` reaches the end of the list, it returns the accumulated value.

We can see syntactically that the first argument is some function that performs some operation on items of type `b` and type `a` to yield a `b`. Now, a function that ignores the `a` item and unconditionally results in whatever the `b` is would fit but wouldn’t be very interesting.

Think about how Horner’s algorithm proceeds. The numbers at the elbows of the path on your diagram represent the notional “result so far” from the previous paragraph. We know that `b` is `Int` and `a` is `Bool`, so the function passed to `foldl` must convert the `Bool` to `Int` and combine it with the result.

The first step in Horner’s algorithm seems to be a special case that needs to be handled differently, but `foldl` uses the same function all the way through. If you imagine “priming the pump” with an invisible horizontal move (*i.e.*, multiplying by two) to begin with, we can make the types fit together like puzzle pieces. It’s fine because two times zero is still zero.

Thus, in terms of `foldl`, Horner’s algorithm is

```hs
horners :: [Bool] -> Int
horners = foldl f 0
  where f x b =
          let b' = fromEnum b
          in 2*x + b'
```

Notice that `2*x + b'` combines subsequent horizontal and vertical moves.

This also suggests how to express it in direct recursion.

```hs
horners' :: [Bool] -> Int
horners' [] = 0
horners' l  = go 0 l
  where -- over then down
        go x [] = x
        go x (b:bs) =
          let b' = fromEnum b
          in go (2*x + b') bs
```

Here the inner `go` loop is performing the left-fold and combining each next `Bool` with the result so far in `i`.

---

<sup>*****</sup> A pedagogical simplification: the actual type generalizes the list type into `Foldable`.